# How to link to a specific implementation of a typeclass function?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I'm writing the documentation for a type-class where I'd like to point to an existing typeclass implementation to given an example of how to write your own instances. Here's what I'm trying:

```
class Something a where

  -- | Please take a look at 'MyModule.complicatedFunction' for an 
  -- example of how to write this function for your own implementations
  -- of this type-class
  complicatedFunction :: a -> Int
```

The generated function *does* link to `MyModule`, but it doesn't link to the MyModule's implementation of `complicatedFunction`, and I don't see a way to link to its source-code either.

Comment: It is my understanding the Haddock doesn't produce documentation for implementations of typeclasses, only the typeclasses themselves, so I don't think there's even any documentation for you to link to in the way you want.

Comment: These days, you *should* see a "source" link to each listed instance. If not, you may be using an older version of Haddock. @Kwarrtz, an instance (but not a method implementation) *can* have a docstring, but unfortunately this will be formatted rather horribly if it's not very short.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the method as a simple synonym to a plain old function, instead of writing the implementation in place.

```
module MyModule where

data MyType = MyConstructor

complicatedFunction_MyType :: MyType -> Int
complicatedFunction_MyType MyConstructor = 734
```

---

```
module YourClass where

class Something a where

  -- | Please take a look at 'MyModule.complicatedFunction_MyType' for an 
  -- example of how to write this function for your own implementations
  -- of this type-class
  complicatedFunction :: a -> Int

instance Something MyType where
  complicatedFunction = complicatedFunction_MyType
```